# change linear layout height programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to change the height of linear layout programmatically. When I use

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

I am getting exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams

Answer (score 8):

I got the solution `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` class as

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: i got the same problem when creating linear layout dynamically i use your solution for setting height and width is working for me.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is you're importing a different LayoutParams.  Try a fully qualified version:

```
ll.setLayoutParams(new android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
    android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
));
```

Answer (score 1):

When you first include LayoutParams in your code and hit Cntrl+Shift+Enter to automatically import the required files, you are displayed a list of all the packages.
Make sure you import the right package in your code.

```
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
```